# Ruby : How to sort an array of hash in a given order of a particular key

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I have an array of hashes, `id` being one of the keys in the hashes. I want to sort the array elements according to a given order of `ID` values.

Suppose my array(size=5) is:

```
[{"id"=>1. ...}, {"id"=>4. ...}, {"id"=>9. ...}, {"id"=>2. ...}, {"id"=>7. ...}]
```

I want to sort the array elements such that their `id`s are in the following order:

```
[1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10]
```

So the expected result is:

```
[{'id' => 1},{'id' => 7},{'id' => 9},{'id' => 2},{'id' => 4}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution for any custom index:

```
def my_index x 
  # Custom code can be added here to handle items not in the index.
  # Currently an error will be raised if item is not part of the index.
  [1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10].index(x) 
end

my_collection = [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>4}, {"id"=>9}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>7}]
p my_collection.sort_by{|x| my_index x['id'] } #=> [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>7}, {"id"=>9}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>4}]
```

Then you can format it in any way you want, maybe this is prettier:

```
my_index = [1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10]
my_collection.sort_by{|x| my_index.index x['id'] }
```

Answer (score 1):

General note on sorting. Use `#sort_by` method of the [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)'s [array](/questions/tagged/array) class:

```
[{'id' => 1},{'id'=>3},{'id'=>2}].sort_by {|x|x['id'] }
# => [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>3}]
```

Or with usage `#values` method as a callback:

```
[{'id' => 1},{'id'=>3},{'id'=>2}].sort_by(&:values)
# => [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>3}]
```

or you can use more obvious version with `#sort` method:

```
[{'id' => 1},{'id'=>3},{'id'=>2}].sort {|x,y| x['id'] <=> y['id'] }
# => [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>3}]
```

For your case, to sort with extended condition use `#%` to split even and odd indexes:

```
[{'id' => 1},{'id'=>4},{'id'=>9},{'id'=>2},{'id'=>7}].sort do |x,y|
    u = y['id'] % 2 <=> x['id'] % 2
    u == 0 && y['id'] <=> x['id'] || u 
end
# => [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>7}, {"id"=>9}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>4}]
```

For your case, to sort with extended condition use `#%` to split according the index, even `id` value is absent in the index array:

```
index = [1,3,5,7,4,2,6,8,10] # swapped 2 and 4, 9 is absent

[{'id' => 1},{'id'=>4},{'id'=>9},{'id'=>2},{'id'=>7}].sort do |x,y|
   !index.rindex( x[ 'id' ] ) && 1 || index.rindex( x[ 'id' ] ) <=> index.rindex( y[ 'id' ] ) || -1 
end
# => [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>7}, {"id"=>4}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>9}]
```

Comment: Expected result is `[{'id' => 1},{'id' => 7},{'id' => 9},{'id' => 2},{'id' => 4}]`

Comment: @Малъ i love clean solutions.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ This would work in this particular case(odds then evens), but is there a general solution. i may have a case where the desirable order will be random

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ : example the desired order is [1,5,3,2,8,9,7,6,4]

Comment: So, take a look at my answer where I already answered the question.

Comment: @hirolau: Ya, I tried your solution and it worked. Sorry I forgot to accept the answer. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I would map the hash based on the values like so:

```
a = [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>4}, {"id"=>9}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>7}]

[1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10].map{|x| a[a.index({"id" => x})] }.compact

#=> [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>7}, {"id"=>9}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `sort`?

```
def doit(arr, order)
  arr.sort { |h1,h2| order.index(h1['id']) <=> order.index(h2['id']) }
end

order = [1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10]
arr = [{'id' => 1}, {'id' => 4}, {'id' => 9}, {'id' => 2}, {'id' => 7}]     

doit(arr, order)
  #=> [{'id' => 1}, {'id' => 7}, {'id' => 9}, {'id' => 2}, {'id' => 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a= [{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>4}, {"id"=>9}, {"id"=>2}, {"id"=>7}]
b=[1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10]
a.sort_by{|x| b.index (x['id'])}
```